# 2d convolution gives not the desired output

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, convolution

I want to use the 2D convolution in the same way I did here in 1D. Unfortunately the output in the former case does not have the desired shape. Let `n = 5`, then

```py
h_0 = (1 / 4) * np.array([1, 2, 1])
x = np.random.rand(n)
np.convolve(h_0, x, 'same')

>>> array([0.65498075, 0.72729356, 0.51417706, 0.34597679, 0.1793755])
```

but

```py
h_00 = np.kron(h_0, h_0)
h_00 = np.reshape(h_00, (3, 3))
x = np.random.rand(n, n)
scipy.signal.convolve2d(h_00, x, 'same', boundary='symm')

>>> array([[1.90147294, 1.6541233 , 1.82704077],
           [1.55228912, 1.3641027 , 1.55536069],
           [1.61190909, 1.45159935, 1.58266083]])
```

I would have expected a `(5, 5)` output array.

Comment: `a` has size 5 - output 5; `h_00` has shape `(3, 3)` output has shape `(3, 3)`. Everything seems reasonable?

Comment: @V.Ayrat I would have expected the output to depend on the size (shape) of ```x```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs for [`scipy.signal.convolve2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) regarding the `mode` parameter clearly state

> **mode**
> ...
> **`same`**
>     The output is the same size as *in1*, centered with respect to the ‘full’ output.

So, given that you pass the kernel first, your output will be the same size as the kernel, not the array you are filtering. To fix, swap the first two inputs:

```
scipy.signal.convolve2d(x, h_00, 'same', boundary='symm')
```

Confusion likely arises from the behavior of [`numpy.convolve`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html), which does the following:

> **mode : *{‘full’, ‘valid’, ‘same’}, optional***
> ...
> **‘same’:**
>     Mode ‘same’ returns output of length `max(M, N)`. Boundary effects are still visible.

Numpy interprets the larger array as the kernel regardless of argument order. This is possible because with a single dimension, there is always an unambiguous winner.